# Adding a new row after a range of rows in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How do I add a new row to a range of existing rows that are ***dynamic*** and are displayed in their own sections in the spread sheet?

E.g. When I click 'add new line' to add ***one row*** to a set of rows:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
ROW 1
-------------------------------------------------------
ROW 2
-------------------------------------------------------
NEW LINE <--- New row is added from the 'add new line'
```

However, this needs to be dynamic to add another line underneath where the number of rows can be different:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
ROW 1
-------------------------------------------------------
ROW 2
-------------------------------------------------------
ROW 3
-------------------------------------------------------
ROW 4
-------------------------------------------------------
NEW LINE <--- New row is added from the 'add new line'
```

The position of the section is passed in as a parameter 'sectionNumber'. Is there a way of using this parameter to find the position of the section of rows then count them and add the new line like above?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
Sub addnewrow()
    Dim addrow As String
    addrow = InputBox("type the row number to insert")
    If addrow <> "" And IsNumeric(addrow) = True Then
        Rows(addrow).Insert shift:=xlDown
    Else
        MsgBox ("enter only row number")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I've edited my question as I forgot to mention that are several sections of rows displayed with the section headings passed into the 'add new line' function

Comment: i am not able to get you. can you please edit some samples

Comment: It's ok, I'm just looking for a solution where I can count the amount of rows in the section. I'm new to VBA as I'm normally c# and unsure how to do it?